# How to read "Leopold Löwenheim" in German?

Tags: person-names, pronouncation

How to read "[Leopold Löwenheim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leopold_L%C3%B6wenheim)" in German? Any native German know it?

Now I need to know the exact pronunciation of "Leopold Löwenheim" (of which I only know the overall pronunciation) to translate it into Chinese from the sound.

If you know, please use the [International Phonetic Alphabet for German](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA/German) to show how to read it.

Comment: You can obtain the pronounciation by looking up Leopold, Löwe and Heim in German Wiktionary and concatenating their respective IPA, placing an n between Löwe and Heim. Also take into account that if two words form a compound, the first one generally gets the stress (here: Löwe).

Comment: Btw, there is no International Phonetic Alphabet for German. There is only one International Phonetic Alphabet, and it's the same for all languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combing statements of @Matthias Ostrowski, @Jonathan Scholbach, @RHa and me, the sound maybe

['le:opɔl̩t 'lø:vnhaɪm]

Any other idea?

Comment: Is this an answer or are you guessing?

Comment: @Alina My answer right now. But I am not very sure.

Answer (score 1):

I pieced it together for you:

le:o:pɔl̩d  lø:vɛnhaɪm

pay attention to the EO in the firstname: both letters are spoken separately and are closed vowels (longer sound). Leopold has 3 syllables!

Löwenheim has the long o-Umlaut and the ei- diphtong prononced as in shine.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I am not sure I agree on "Leopold has 3 syllables". To me, the o is short.

Comment: Even if both o's are short, it's still three syllables. To read it as two syllables, eo has to be read as a diphtong, but as far as I know no speaker of German does this.

Comment: [le:o:pɔl̩d] is not quite correct as it lacks the Auslautverhärtung. Correct is ˈ[leːopɔlt].

Comment: @RHa Could you give your answer independently?

Comment: Also, I see [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Löwen#German) that the first e in Löwenheim doesn't sound, and so I don't know which one should I follow.

Comment: I am no linguist. I could agree with the t at the end of leopold. I looked for a harder t sound, but the examples suggested to go with d. But I stand with the closed o at the beginning of leopold and the pronounced e in the middle of löwenheim. Everything else seems only like sloppy speaking habits and not Hochdeutsche Aussprache.